# How to return the serial primary key from a db insert to use for another db insert

Tags: postgresql, rest, express, pg-promise

I'm using the express generated template with postgresql and I have 2 rest route methods for creating consignments and tracking. 
However i want tracking to be updated on each consignment insert, but i require the serial primary key to do it. So from the createCon function i require it to return the id after the insert, to use for the cid field in the createConTracking.

routes/index.js file

```
var db = require('../queries');
router.post('/api/cons', db.createCon);
router.post('/api/cons/:id/tracking', db.createConTracking);
```

queries.js

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
var options = {
  promiseLib: promise
};
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var db = pgp(connectionString);
function createCon(req, res, next) {
  var conid = parseInt(req.body.conid);
  db.none('insert into consignments(conid, payterm,........)'+
    'values($1, $2, ......)',
    [conid, req.body.payterm,........])
    .then(function () {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Inserted one con'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}

function createConTracking(req, res, next) {
  var cid = parseInt(req.params.id);
  var userid = req.user.email;
  var conid = parseInt(req.body.conid);
  db.none('insert into tracking(status, remarks, depot, userid, date, cid, conid)'+
    'values($1, $2, $3, $4,$5, $6, $7)',
    [req.body.status, req.body.remarks, req.body.depot, userid, req.body.date, cid, conid])
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          data:   data,
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Updated Tracking'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

DB

```
CREATE TABLE consignments (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  conId INTEGER,
  payTerm VARCHAR,

CREATE TABLE tracking (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  status VARCHAR,
  remarks VARCHAR,
  cid INTEGER
  );
```

Comment: Your code example is confusing. Your requirements are for a single HTTP handler that performs two operations, not for two separate HTTP handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

You should execute multiple queries within a task (method [task](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#task)) when not changing data, or transaction (method [tx](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx)) when changing data. And in case of making two changes to the database, like in your example, it should be a transaction.

You would append `RETURNING id` to your first insert query and then use method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one) to indicate that you expect one row back.

```
function myRequestHandler(req, res, next) {
    db.tx(async t => {
        const id = await t.one('INSERT INTO consignments(...) VALUES(...) RETURNING id', [param1, etc], c => +c.id);
        return t.none('INSERT INTO tracking(...) VALUES(...)', [id, etc]);
    })
        .then(() => {
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'Inserted a consignment + tracking'
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return next(error);
        });
}
```

In the example above we execute the two queries inside a transaction. And for the first query we use the third parameter for an easy return value transformation, plus conversion (in case it is a 64-bit like `BIGSERIAL`).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) clause to your [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) statement.  This clause allows you to return data concerning the actual values in the inserted record.

```
insert into consignments(conid, payterm,........)
values($1, $2, ......)
returning id;
```

Comment: In addition to the answer I would say you dont have to use `db.none(...)` method if your query return something.